# c linux sockets: check for existing connections from client side

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have the following setup:

- 2 Ubuntu machines (server and client)
- on the "server" I'm running this to echo all the data received back to the sender (the client):

  ```
  ncat -e /bin/cat -v -l 12345
  ```
- on the client I have simple application which just connects to the remote socket: socket() -> setsockopt() -> connect()

So... my question is: Is it possible to check if there are other applications already connected to the socket from the ***client*** application? I want only one process connected to the socket at any given time and I want to check this from the client application. Is this possible? After 3h googling I couldn't find anything relevant :(

(sorry, no experience with network programming)

Comment: Let me clarify: in the client app I want something like this:if (num_connections > 1) then cancel connection. The problem is I can't get the existing connections. I was thinking about something like getsockopt(SO_PEERCRED) but it's not working as I expected :)

Answer (score 2):

No, a client is not able to see how many other clients are connected to a server.

To be able to retrieve this information an application specific protocol needs to be used on client and server.

Anyhow there is this one special case: If the client knows that a maximum of N clients can connect to the server, and it's own try to connect is refused it could assume that N clients are connected to the server already.

---

To set the maximum number of connections `ncat` handles in parallel use it's option `-m`/`--max-conns`. Verbatim form `man ncat`:

> **-m numconns, --max-conns numconns** (Specify max number of connections) .
>              The maximum number of simultaneous connections accepted for an Ncat instance. 100 is the default.

Comment: Before posting this question I tried with the -m option. With "-m 1" I'm still able to connect second time (even though ncat prints "New connection denied: connection limit reached") but I can't send/receive data. I want to restrict the connection itself if possible.

Comment: @Meh: As I wote in my answer, it is not possible for the client to get any info from the server without talking to it, which implies connecting to it on socket level.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
netstat -an | grep <your server port port number>
```

on your client machine to see any existing TCP connections.

Comment: I think this should be the answer. You can get the output here, apply regex or count lines  and apply you logic.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not close the listening socket on the server after you've accepted one client? If there's no listening socket no more clients will be able to connect. Once you've dropped your one client, you can then open the listening socket again, ready for one more. That way the client will see a "failure" to connect if the server is busy, or will succeed normally otherwise.

The down side of this approach is that the client won't be able to determine exactly why it can't connect, it could be because the client is busy (has its one client) or it could be because of other issues. Does this matter?